# Toggle show/hide div in html table

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I need to be able to click on the image in one of the cells to display a table of details generated by a query. Below is a small example of the code. Why is the second row displays if div's display is set to none?

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Show/Hide Test</title>
       <script>
            function showDeta() {
            var x = document.getElementById("details");
            if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
            }   
        </script>      
    </head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Blah <image id="x" src="details.png" onClick="showDeta(this)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <div id="details" style="display:none;">        
            <tr>
                <td>Details of Blah</td>
            </tr>
        </div>           
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Because `tr` and `div` cannot be siblings. The `div` is invalid as a direct child of `table`.

Comment: What are my options in this case?

Comment: The most straightforward would be to put the id and style from the div on the 2nd tr: `<tr id="details" style="display:none;"` Or put the div inside the 2nd tr and td.

Comment: Thanks Myka, I wrapped detail rows into <table  id="details" style="display:none;"> It looks like it's working. I do not know how to give you credit for your answer though.

Comment: I put my answer below; you can accept it there. Thanks!

Comment: Since <script> gets element by id, how do I manage them if I have more that one row to click on?

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a `<div>` cannot be a direct child of a `<table>`, the most straightforward way to achieve your goal would be to put the id and style from the  on the 2nd : `<tr id="details" style="display:none;"` Or put the div inside the 2nd tr and td.

To answer the question you added in the comments:
Turn your `id="detail"` into a class. For simplicity, I'm adding a `<tbody>` for each set of related `<tr>` tags. Pass the event into the function and use the event to find the related details.

```js
            function showDeta(e) {
            var x = e.currentTarget.closest("tbody").querySelector(".details");
            if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
            }
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Blah <image id="x" src="details.png" onClick="showDeta(event)" /></td>
        </tr>  
            <tr class="details" style="display:none;">
                <td>1 Details of Blah</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Blah <image id="x" src="details.png" onClick="showDeta(event)" /></td>
        </tr>  
            <tr class="details" style="display:none;">
                <td>2 Details of Blah</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` can not be a child of `div`.

However a `div` can be a child of `tr` -> `td`.